# i want a regex which can accept only up to 60 after decimal point

Tags: regex

I want a regex which can accept only up to 60 after the decimal point ... `0.0` to `7.60`.

The following regex accepts till .60 but it does not accept the second decimal place more than 6, like `0.39`  or `0.59`

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-6]{1,2})?$
```

I want a regex which can accept any numbers, but only numbers up to 60 after decimal point.

Comment: this is an inappropriate use of regular expressions, they aren't designed for this kind of logic

Comment: Regex isn't quite the right too, here, but something like what @Guido's suggesting is right.

Comment: There is no reason regex is inappropriate here; this is an easy problem to solve with regex, and is actually more complicated with string parsing and if/else blocks.

Comment: parsing this into a actual number and doing `>= 0.0 and <= 7.60` is much more explicit and clear than processing the **textual** representation. Every modern language can parse this into the actual number in a much clearer manner for future maintainers. Processing numbers as text and doing numerical operations on the text is just backwards and bad advice and technique.

Comment: @user3370584: please clarify where you allow more than 2 digits after the decimal place.

Comment: Is the value `3.8` allowed?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You just need to use `[0-5][0-9]?` after the decimal, but also allow for `.6` or `.60`:

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-5][0-9]?|\.60?)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/p1FT-T2JCZ8XeRVC)

*Edited to fix error pointed out in comments.*

**Note:** Your question indicates that you may want to limit the range to a max of `7.60`. If so, just replace the initial `[0-9]+` with `[0-7]`:

```
^[0-7](\.[0-5][0-9]?|\.60?)?$
```

Comment: this allows `7.69` which is outside the range of what they are asking for, the regex that is needed is extremely complex, and isn't a good idea to try and do this kind of logic, that isn't what regular expressions are meant to be used for.

Comment: You're both right; I fixed it. @JarrodRoberson: the logic isn't that complex. As regexes go, this isn't so bad. Parsing a string and validating its format is a perfect job for a regex.

Comment: I don't think this matches; the number `0.591111` is between `0.0` and `7.60` and your update doesn't match against that. Would be a good idea to clarify with @user3370584

Comment: @EdCottrell: What Jarrod has explained is right. Regex are not for this. And you can exploit your Regex using this Microsoft online tool:   http://rise4fun.com/rex

Comment: Without getting into a debate about the merits and uses of regex, I'm trying to answer OP's question. @skumar: You didn't actually post a link for whatever "exploit" you are referring to.

Comment: @DeanTaylor i just want the regex till two decimal places so the answer that Ed Cottrell gave solves my question

Comment: @user3370584 In that case, please remember to select an answer! :)

Comment: @skumar There are no exploits there - nothing about the behavior it identified was unexpected.

Comment: @EdCottrell: I am not telling it is regex exploit but the reson behind sharing the url is it shows all the possible combination where the regex will fail.